# how to filter json array and store under alphabetical caption?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

example json array:

```
[  { "companyName" : "Amazon",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "AT&T",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "Birla Tech",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "Capgemini",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 }]
```

i want filter this array and store it like companyName starts with A should in separate 'A' array.. and CompanyName starts with B should be in  'B' array.  How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its a `groupBy` you wanna do. Look at

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Underscore can also do groupby, probably other libraries too, or create your own.

Update: I rolled my own for you

```
function groupBy(items, getKey) {
    var grouped = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       var key = getKey(items[i]);        
        if(grouped[key] === undefined) {
           grouped[key] = [];
        }

        grouped[key].push(items[i]);
    }

    return grouped;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgej2/

Answer (score 0):

Create an object where each key is a letter containing an array of company information objects related to that letter:

```
var out = {};

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {

  // get the first letter of the company name and capitalise it
  var letter = arr[i].companyName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  // if the letter doesn't exist in the output object create it as an array
  if (!out[letter]) { out[letter] = []; }

  // push the company object to the array
  out[letter].push(arr[i]);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ddc6Q/1)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this, I understood and I made this,
check out this once and ask what you exact needed.Below is the code for you...

```
    my =[  { "companyName" : "Amazon",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "AT&T",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "Birla Tech",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 },
 { "companyName" : "Capgemini",
   "assets": 35,
    "users": 3 
 }];
var result=[];
var isFound=false;
my.forEach(function(a){

    for(var j=0; j< result.length; j++){

        if(a.companyName[0]==Object.keys(result[j])[0]){
            isFound=true;
            temp=result[j];
            temp[a.companyName[0]].push(a);
        }else {
            isFound=false;
        }
    }

    if(!isFound){
        temp={};
        temp[a.companyName[0]]=[a];
        result.push(temp);
    }

});
console.log(my);
```